# SQL Group An Already Grouped Result

Tags: sql, group-by

I have to perform the following on some table:

1. I need to group it first based on something
   and then
2. I need to group the previous result again based on something else.

Is there any way to do both groupings in single query?

Comment: wrap the first grouped result in a subquery. please add some sample records.

Comment: @JW, did that, but it takes a really long time.

Comment: @BabuJames Work on performance tuning for your query.

Answer (score 1):

you should check your wanted results by those two methods:

```
select *
from (
   select *
   from table
   group by acol
)
group by bcol



select *
from table
group by acol, bcol
```

try those two, they should help

Comment: I have tried the first variant. I have about 54,00,000 records to fetch. First method takes a really long time. Second method wont help as I need to have some aggregate methods to be used on the result of first group.

Comment: so I would suggest to add some indexes to your table. it would be better if you could post your table so we could help you better.

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier for us to help you if you show us some code as "J W" requested. With not much information on the structure of your query, let me give it a shot. Are you trying to do something like this:

```
WITH    FirstGroup
AS      (            
        SELECT  Color, ReorderPoint, COUNT(*) Items
        FROM    Production.Product
        GROUP   BY Color, ReorderPoint        
        )
SELECT  Color, SUM(ReorderPoint), SUM(Items) TotalItems
FROM    FirstGroup
GROUP   BY Color
```

*NOTE: I used the AdventureWorks database*